# Diffusion equation

Tags: statistical-mechanics

How is the simple diffusion equation (1-dim and constant diffusion coefficient), to be reformulated if diffusion takes place in a simple (linear) potential, for example particles in a gravity or charges in a homogeneous electric field?

Comment: Fokker Planck equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Kramers_equation